# Cant access files on Azure Blob Storage from within Canvas App

Tags: security, networking, azure-blob-storage, powerapps

I am trying to secure my blob storage so that only requests coming from within my canvas app are accepted by ABS. From within the storage accounts networking tab I have choosen **Allow access from: Selected networks** and have added the IP addresses [outlined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/limits-and-config#ip-addresses) for my region, which is Australia.

[image]

But I still get a AuthorizationFailure error when trying to access a document through a shared link created by ABS from within my cavas app.

When I allow All networks everything works fine.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: What's the request IP address?

Comment: Not sure as its coming from PowerApps, I added all the IP address ranges Microsoft specify but still no dice.

Comment: I have not used PowerApps (so please pardon my ignorance) but is your application consumed through a browser? That could explain about the error you're getting as the IP address will be that of the client machine.